# Click event - add html element everytime i click - Pure js

Tags: javascript, html

Hello everyone i have probably a small problem and i don't know how to fix that , i need `onclick` event that every time i click it add html code , i don't wanna use `innerHTML` because its risky, this is the code:

```
button.addEventListener('click',function () {
    const elements = `<div class="list-elem ${classList} data-id=${id}">
            <div class="to-do-date">
                <h3>${myDateString + ' ' + myTimeString}</h3>
            </div>
            <i class="fas fa-times" style="display: flex;"></i>
            <div class="to-do-topic">
                <h1>${topic.value}</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="to-do-text">
                <p>${textarea.value}</p>
            </div>
        </div>`
    toDoLists.appendChild(elements);
    id++
})
```

if i use `append()` it works like this:

**Append looks like this**

[image]

And if i use appendChild() i have this error below:

> TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.

Probably i'm dumb and the fix way is easy, anyways i want to make it in pure JS without jquery.

I hope i can get help here , thanks :)

Comment: You're using appendchild, which adds the string as a text node.

Comment: Looks like it's a jquery object try `toDoLists.get(-1).appendChild(elements);`

Comment: TypeError: toDoLists.get is not a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you must use `insertAdjacentHTML` function like below. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
var button = document.getElementById('btn');
var toDoLists = document.getElementById('toDoLists');

var id = 1,
  classList = "classList",
  myDateString = "6 May 2018",
  myTimeString = "21:56:13",
  topic = {
    value: 13
  },
  textarea = {
    value: 131313
  };

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const elements = `<div class="list-elem ${classList} data-id=${id}">
            <div class="to-do-date">
                <h3>${myDateString + ' ' + myTimeString}</h3>
            </div>
            <i class="fas fa-times" style="display: flex;"></i>
            <div class="to-do-topic">
                <h1>${topic.value}</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="to-do-text">
                <p>${textarea.value}</p>
            </div>
        </div>`
  toDoLists.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', elements);
  id++;
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
<div id="toDoLists"></div>
```

Comment: Ok this works really goood i didn't know about "insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', elements);" need to read about it , is it safe to use ?

Comment: I prefer using `js` libraries and frameworks than using pure js. I don't know a lot about this function. But consider these tips https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML#Security_Considerations @Mariusz

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example (with most of your code) of a way to append html after an element:
(See comments in my code)

```js
// Code below to make a working example
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var toDoLists = document.getElementById("toDoLists");

var id = 1,
  classList = "classList",
  myDateString = "xx/xx/xxxx",
  myTimeString = "hh:mm:ss",
  topic = {
    value: "Topic"
  },
  textarea = {
    value: "Text in text area"
  };

// Here below, your code modified
button.addEventListener('click', function() {

  // Creates a div and fill it with the html you wanted
  var elements = document.createElement("div");
  elements.innerHTML = `<div class="list-elem ${classList} data-id=${id}">
        <div class="to-do-date">
            <h3>${myDateString + ' ' + myTimeString}</h3>
        </div>
        <i class="fas fa-times" style="display: flex;"></i>
        <div class="to-do-topic">
            <h1>${topic.value}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="to-do-text">
            <p>${textarea.value}</p>
        </div>
    </div>`;

  toDoLists.appendChild(elements);
  // id++ // Disabled because fixed values for example !
})
```

```css
/* Some styling */

.list-elem {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">It's me, the button</button>
<br /><br />
<div id="toDoLists">Here is the to-do list:</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: "i don't wanna use innerHTML because its risky," i dont wanna use innerHTML bro :( i have working code for innerhtml , but im nopt sure if there is way to do it without that.

Comment: @Mariusz, sorry, I missed that !

Comment: its fine , but the second method is not safe too :<

Comment: @Mariusz You may unaccept the answer and clarify this "safe" issue in your question.